# How to resize an image proportionally using a blur effect, instead of letterboxing, on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp, jimp

I have a photo which is a rectangle and I want to resize it down to a square while **preserving the aspect ratio**. Libraries like [Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) allow you to do that by applying **letterboxing** to the resulting image.

```
await sharp(photoBuffer).resize({ width: 200, height: 200, fit: 'contain' })
```

This is the result:

[image: with letterboxing]

Instead of applying letterboxing I'd like the remaining empty space to be filled with a 2nd **blurred** version of the image, placed behind the resized one, like so:

[image: example]

Is there a Node.js library that does that out of the box or some custom way of achieving this ?

Comment: Isn't ImageMagick the standard for backend image processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is how you do it using Sharp:

```
import Sharp from 'sharp'

export default function({ pathToInputFile, pathToOutputFile, size, blur }) {
  let sharpOriginal = Sharp(pathToInputFile)
  
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    sharpOriginal
      .resize({ width: size })
      .toBuffer()
      .then((resizedBuffer) => {
        sharpOriginal
          .resize(size, size, { // the result will be a square
            fit: 'cover'
          })
          .blur(blur) // 6 seems to work well
          .composite([{
            input: resizedBuffer,
            gravity: 'center'
          }])
          .toFile(pathToOutputFile)
          .then((info) => {
            console.log(info)
            resolve(true)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
            resolve(false)
          })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
        resolve(false)
      })
  })
}
```